# Use both versions of Google cloud resource management Java API in the same project

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, resource-management

Currently I'm working on a Java project which needs to have `Google Cloud` integration.

I need to get all folders and all projects from a service account using `Cloud Resource Management API`.

The problem is folders are new and only available in **version 2** of the API, but projects are in **version 1**. I cannot include 2 `jar` files because the there will be conflict and only one of them will be used.

Does anyone have similar issue and solved the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, you can make two programs, one for each API, and make them talk to each other (Have one launch the other).

Have the version 2 program grab all the folder info you need, and the pass the relevant parts to your program with the version 1 API.

It's not great, but it works.

---

Better yet you could make a converter to update each project as it is opened, so that it will only use the version 2 API going forward.